# I get NA using as.Date in r

Tags: r, na, as.date

When I use the "as.Date" command in r it returns Na as results, I have tried different things like transforming it to POSIXt format, but it doesn't work

```
#this is the format i need it to read
format(Sys.Date(), "%B de %Y")

# this is an example of what i need
date="noviembre de 2022"
class(date)

#this is what i tried
date2 <- strptime(date, format = "%B de %Y")
class(date2)
date3 <- as.Date(date2,format="%B de %Y")
class(date3)
date3
```

This is what i get
[na as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb1AI.png)

I would like to have something similar to this

```
navidad2021=as.Date("25 Diciembre 2021",format="%d %B %Y")
navidad2021
[1] "2021-12-25"
```

But in this format

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%B de %Y")
[1] "December de 2022"
```

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are looking for in an answer? My answer demonstrated how to convert from the format "November de 2022" into a Date, and how to make the Date format in R print like your format. Is that different from what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT- I may've misunderstood your intention. If you want to create a date from the phrase "November de 2022" (my computer's local settings use english), we could do this by manipulating the string to add "1 " at the start and to remove "de " from the middle -- then it parses.

```
date="November de 2022"
as.Date(paste(1, gsub("de ", "", date)), format = "%d %B %Y")
[1] "2022-11-01"
```

---

Date is one of the built-in data types in R. When you print a Date, it uses the built-in `print.Date` function to show it as YYYY-MM-DD. You can also create a character string (as you have done) to display a Date using another format, but then it will cease to be a Date you can manipulate.

You could overwrite `print.Date` on your system if you want it to print differently.

```
print.Date <- function (x, max = NULL, ...) 
{
  if (is.null(max)) 
    max <- getOption("max.print", 9999L)
  if (max < length(x)) {
    print(format(x[seq_len(max)]), max = max + 1, ...)
    cat(" [ reached 'max' / getOption(\"max.print\") -- omitted", 
        length(x) - max, "entries ]\n")
  }
  else if (length(x)) 
    print(format(x, "%B de %Y"), max = max, ...)
  else cat(class(x)[1L], "of length 0\n")
  invisible(x)
}

as.Date("2021-12-25")
[1] "December de 2021"
as.Date("2021-12-25") + 7
[1] "January de 2022"
```

However, this will not work for others unless you overwrite their `print.Date` as well, which is bad form.